# Kibana Dashboard: Why doesn't "QUERY" work?

Tags: kibana, kibana-3

I'm pretty new to kibana and I kind of understood that "query" and "filter" do the same work. There is some difference in the way that cache handles them.

I'm trying to search for all the results that have type "clicks".

[image]

If I do it by using "filtering", it works good. All the results I get have type "clicks". However, if I cancel the option for filtering and write "query: clicks" in the query field, it seems that Kibana ignores my request and basically shows me all the results that passed the "filtering".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've taken a look at the explanation of how queries are handled 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/3.0/queries.html

Maybe the *clicks* has to be in quotation marks? I am using kibana 5+ so I am not familiar with this feature.